# Как центрировать карту на маркер после смены размера карты?

Tags: google-maps-api, javascript

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<Title>No Title </title>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
 body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px } 
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(100.00,100.00);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
 var  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(100.00,100.00);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          title: 'Magazin',
          map: map

  });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
document.getElementById("table").style.width ='80%'; 
map.setZoom(13); 
myLatlng =  new google.maps.LatLng(marker.getPosition());

});}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width=100% height=100% ><tr><td width=100% id="table">
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
<td>

</table>  
</body>
</html>
```

Хочу чтобы при нажатие на маркер появлялась информация о магазине (справа)

Дело в том, что после того, как изменяется размер Table, маркер остается на том же месте, где раньше был центр. 
Стоит мне изменить размер окна и, вуаля, маркер встает по центру. Как сделать чтобы он сразу встал туда?

Извиняюсь, код был не очень корректен (исправил)

```
myLatlng =  new google.maps.LatLng(marker.getPosition());
```

Эта строчка вроде должна менять центр карты на маркер

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){
        map.setCenter( marker.getPosition() );
    });
```

Работает точно так же, т.е. 
карта центрируется на маркер но это не совсем центр (это тот старый центр), карта уменьшилась в размерах (с права на 20%) то и центр должен сдвинуться (на 10% от центра в левую сторону)

Нет, парни все дело не в этом. т.е. это то же самое плавно, не плавно, без разницы, центр (маркер) остаются на старом месте после изменения размера таблицы, если я уменьшу таблицу до 40%, то он вообще исчезнет из поля видимости.

Comment: @KuHoMaH, не нужно писать уточнения к вопросу в виде ответов.

Comment: Так как данную проблему решили?

Answer (score 2):

У карты есть событие `zoom_changed`. На него можно повесить обработчик, которым будет устанавливаться центральная точка.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){
    map.setCenter( marker.getPosition() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть более прекрасное решение: методом

```
yourMap.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(userLat, userLong));
```

Тут прокрутка произойдет плавно, а не так что сразу в центр ляснет ;)

Comment: помог, еще и повеселил :)